# Storing Data In variable using Reactjs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm Using React and nodejs I can successfully retrieve the data but I'm Unable to store it in a variable

```
 OnSubmit(e){
    
    const user={
      email:this.state.email,
      password:this.state.password,
      
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>(console.log(res.data)))//want to store this res.data in a variable
    
    
    
    
    
    
    localStorage.setItem("token","got")
    
    this.setState({
      loggedin:true
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

In arrow function, Paranethesis `()` has implicit return statement and can contain only single statement. Whereas, brace `{}` need explicit return statement and you can add multiple statements inside scope.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=> {
       // Here, you can do required manipulation of data returned from promise
       console.log(res.data)
       
       localStorage.setItem("token","got")
    
       this.setState({ loggedin:true })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this:

```
let userDetails = null;
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>{userDetails = res.data})
```

but if you want to use it outside the async call, then the value of userDetails will be null, as this is an Async fetch, so you can set this value in the state inside .then() like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>{this.setState({userDetails: res.data})})
```

Comment: I have saved data in a variable like this   axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>{
     Userdata=res.data.users
      console.log(Userdata)
      console.log(Userdata._id)
       
    }) But I'm unable to use it in the render() function if(this.state.loggedin){
  
      return <Redirect to={`/UI/Navbar/Dashboard/${Userdata._id}`}/>
    }   it gives me an error  TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: to use it in render, you should set this value in state as I mentioned in my answer, then use it like this: <Redirect to={/UI/Navbar/Dashboard/${this.state.userDetails._id}}/>

Comment: tried as you said but it still gives me the same error

Comment: try to log userDetails, maybe it doesn't have _id, or it's nested more

Answer (score 1):

You can either same that to a variable or to your React state (class component) or to hooks. Multiple ways are available:
class based component:
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
.then(res=>this.setState({data:res.data}))

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable in state, say "userData: null";
then do this,

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
.then(res=>{
 // try to console.log `res` and checkout its hierarchy. 
 this.setState({userData: res.data});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/Users/login',user)
    .then(res=>{this.setState({userDetails: res.data})})
```

Comment: Or no need for setting this in the state if you want to store this in local storage